# Sending data between 2 flash apps

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, send

I would like to create android/ios app that has a feature like candy crash life sending.
Is it possible in as3 to create such thing?
Do I need to use a server side or it can be done with flash and as3?

Answer (score -1):

Short and simple: YES, most definitely you'll need server.

Also, bear in mind that if you plan to sell goods in the game or similar - you will need to verify the data send from the flash on the server. It's pretty easy to decompile the swf, make changes to say have unlimited moves, compile again and play.

If you're planing that, I'll suggest to make more research on how to make a "secure" game, since flash in general is considered as unsafe...

Comment: "since flash in general is considered as unsafe..."  Downvote

Comment: @Jeff Ward why downvote? It is unsecured, you should never trust the data send from the flash client to the server. Is too easy to hack the flash, even if you use tools like SecureSWF or similar ...

Comment: Explaining the security concerns of client / server communication is one thing, while blanket statements without supporting info like the above will irritate people.